# Splitting a txt file with many tables to a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, txt

I have a txt file which is downloaded from a website. This txt file has many observations and different tables.

An example would be:

Table 1

```
"{'ID':'1','Column A':'Observation A', 'Column B':'Observation B',...}"

"{'ID':'2','Column A':'Observation G', 'Column C':'Observation E',...}"
```

Table 2

```
"{'ID':'3', 'Column A':'Observation I', 'Column C': Observation B',...}"

"{'ID':'4','Column I':'Observation A', 'Column B':'Observation B',...}"
```

What I would like to do, is open the file, split the data to different observations, although list the observations under their Columns. If an ID does not have a column but the column appears in a previous ID, the observation under that column should be listed as N/A or 0. Otherwise, if a column did not appear before, add it as a new column and fill the observations of the previous IDs that did not have this column with 0 or N/A. An example, taking into consideration the above table demonstration, would be:

```
'ID','Column A','Column B','Column C', 'Column I'

 '3', 'I'      ,'N/A'    , 'B'       , 'N/A'
```

At the moment I have loaded and read the data with `open(str)` to open the file. Used Regex to split the data to many observations and then develop a dataframe, although ended up with 1 column, with each row containing all data of each ID. I have thought of using regex to split further using the delimeter, and then loop through all odd numbers of each ID, in order to identify and append (by using the .extend method) a list of columns of each IDs (that could belong to any table). However, if there is an observation with a comma delimeter, this method would result in an error.

Is there a better method to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a solution.

As a first step, I have opened the txt file using an encoding that would not discard any of the data, including diffeerent language, or symbols as explained in the [in-built functions of python here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

```
with open ('sample.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    dataoftxt = file.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Afterwards I have used [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), to split the data and separate the codes from the observations. Due to the nature of the data, I selected `':'` and `',"'` as the separators, allowing me to separate column names from observation values. Since the common structure of a table always list the names of the columns first, and then the value of the observation, the split separates all columns to odd numbers (i.e. 1 Column_name, 2 Value, 3 Column_name...). Using `temp.iloc` I have managed to only pull the data of the columns and afterwards performed a `.drop_duplicate` function to delete the columns that appear multiple times due to the different number of IDs.

```
import re
column_names = pd.DataFrame(re.split(':|,"', dataoftxt))
column_names[0] = temp.iloc[1::2] #takes only the odd numbers of the column 0
column_names = column_names.reset_index(drop=True) #resets the index
column_names = column_names.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True) #remove duplicate columns
```

Once the code is executed, I manually check the data using `print(column_names.to_string)` and remove any columns that do not qualify as columns, based on certain regulations.